# Lightsail Bitnami instance gets redirected

Tags: amazon-web-services, static, ip, bitnami

I used AWS Lightsail to create an Bitnami WordPress instance. The instructions then say to put my static ip in the address of a browser and it should open the default Bitnami page on the instance. But when I put the static IP address into a browser, it redirects to [http://54.200.211.244.nip.io/wp-signup.php?new=[my](http://54.200.211.244.nip.io/wp-signup.php?new=%5Bmy) IP address].nip.io. How do I get to the page at my static IP address?

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. I think you deployed a Bitnami WordPress Multisite solution in Lightsail, right? In that case, a domain is required to work with the solution and that's why you get redirected to the [nip.io wildcard domain](https://nip.io/). You can't log in to the application using the IP and that's why we configure that. If you have a valid domain, you can configure and access the application using it

Comment: Thank you for your response, Jota. Ah, got it. Since it's a multisite instance, each address would have to be declared. I was just following the video [https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/log-in-to-your-bitnami-application-running-on-amazon-lightsail] and it shows copying and pasting the static IP address into the web browser. I bet that only works for a single site instance. All makes sense now. Thank you for your help!